# Add suffix to string only if not already present

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a (GNU) Makefile, I want to add an optional `DESTDIR` prefix to a path (which may or may not be absolute), as in:

- The original path is `${DIR}` (always defined and non-empty);
- The `DESTDIR` variable specified by the user may be empty, and it may or may not terminate with a slash.

I want in all cases the resulting `${DESTDIR}` + `${DIR}` concatenation to be a valid path and without double slashes. That is:

- if `DESTDIR` is empty or ends with a slash, just do `${DESTDIR}${DIR}`;
- otherwise, do `${DESTDIR}/${DIR}`.

The following does seem to work (at least on a few tests):

```
ifeq (${DESTDIR},)
# DESTDIR is empty
FULLDIR:=${DIR}
else
ifeq ($(patsubst %/,$,${DESTDIR}),${DESTDIR})
# DESTDIR has no trailing slash
FULLDIR:=${DESTDIR}/${DIR}
else
# DESTDIR has a trailing slash
FULLDIR:=${DESTDIR}${DIR}
endif
endif
$(info FULLDIR: ${FULLDIR})
```

But it is very cumbersome. Is there a simpler/shorter way to obtain the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FULLDIR := $(if ${DESTDIR},$(patsubst %/,%,${DESTDIR})/${DIR},${DIR})
```

Answer (score 2):

GNU Make has some built-in functions to manipulate file names.

Ones in your interest might be `$(abspath *files...*)` and `$(realpath *files...*)`.

Both functions will take your path and convert it to canonical absolute path, which is absolute path without repeating slash, `..` and `.`. Only difference is that `realpath` will resolve symlinks but `abspath` will not.

Though if you want something not absolute path, only thing I can tell is there's no easy way for it. One may try creating regex that replaces repeating slash into one and use `$(shell)` function with regex command line utility, but it will still contain a lot of ambiguity like having `..` or three slashes in a row.

So my recommendation is to do `$(realpath ${DESTDIR}/${DIR})`.